# Will google block my IP if I connect every 10 seconds with this code?

Tags: c#, networking, timer, connection

I have written a small code snippet to check internet connectivity every 10 seconds.

here's my code:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
var result = client.BeginConnect("www.google.com",80, null, null);
var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // <- timeout value is 2 seconds

if (success)
{
    Status = ConnectionStatus.Connected;
    // we have connected
    client.EndConnect(result);
}
else
{
    Status = ConnectionStatus.Disconnected;
}
```

My only concern is, if I connect to google every 10 seconds, will they think that I am some kind of spam attack or something and block me ?

If yes, is there other reliable target I can user instead of google ?

Comment: in this case test your connection on other web page, which doesn't has security/spam issues !

Comment: can't you just ping google.com or 8.8.8.8 (google DNS server) instead of connecting to web server? ping is less resource consuming on both sides.

Comment: Setup your own server instead of abusing google's servers.

Comment: @bansi Ping isnt working for me for any website or even 8.8.8.8 May me the ISP has blocked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also check for sites like:
http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Then you can also retrieve your IP and check if it has changed somehow compared to an already known IP address.

Comment: Did connect to www.whatsmyip.org. Thanks. Hope they don't mind a connection every 10 seconds.